# Define default route / Symfony4 ( including URL)

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm testing the router of Symfony4.

At the file **routes.yaml** i have the following:

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::login

login_check:
    path: /login_check

logout:
    path: /logout
```

This only renders the view login at the URL "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", in my case i want redirect entire URL, i mean if i place http://127.0.0.1:8000/ i want be redirected http://127.0.0.1:8000/login as my main page. Cos in this controller i check if user has session or not, if have is being redirected to private view, if not is able to login.

If i try to log in through http://127.0.0.1:8000 controller has no response, so user can't log in.

How can achieve this?

Thanks for your time.

Kind regards.

Comment: Hello!, have you considered making a controller in "/" to redirect to "/login"?

Comment: I never thought about it. May be this solve the situation :lol: :D

Comment: Glad to know it worked! :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

as Danipilot said, this solves the situation:

Removing index: path from routes.yaml and creating a controller with the function:

```
/**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */
    public function index()
    {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
}
```